In PyQt6, what's a good approach to make an animated background for widgets?
In QT, you can use a QLabel and QMovie to play a gif. I want other widgets to be in front of an animated background, but you can't place other widgets in QLabel.
For example, I have this dialog. Every widget there is placed in a QFrame main_frame

Here is what I'm trying to achieve, here I used a static image as the background on the main_frame. I want to get the same effect, but with a gif, or another method that could make the background animated and not static.

I've tried looking for solutions online, but people don't seem to be using animated backgrounds.

You cannot do that in Designer, but it's enough to programmatically create a QLabel as child of the dialog, without adding it to the layout, then update its size in the window's resizeEvent().

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
